# web form client with identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

Hi:

I see that asp.net web form client is missing in samples. I have identity server setup with asp.net identity and clients and scopes being saved in database with entity framework. i have api in asp.net core and an mvc application in core which gets token from identity server. it works with these configurations:

```
   var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",

            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ClientId = "mvcClient",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            //GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            ResponseType = "code id_token", // hybrid flow
            //RemoteSignOutPath = "/Account/LogOff"
            //Scope = { "NamfusAPI", "offline_access" },
             SaveTokens = true
        };


        oidcOptions.Scope.Clear();
        oidcOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
        oidcOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
        oidcOptions.Scope.Add("NamfusAPI");
        oidcOptions.Scope.Add("offline_access");


        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

but when i try asp.net web form (developed in .net 4.6.1) with this configuration:

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary();

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        //LoginPath = new PathString(ConstansValues.BaseAddress + @"permissions/")
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "mvcClient",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
        Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5969",
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5969",
        ResponseType = "code id_token",              
        Scope = "openid profile NamfusAPI offline_access",

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
            {

                var token = n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;
                // persist access token in cookie
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(
                        new Claim("access_token", token));
                }
                var nid = new ClaimsIdentity();
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim(@"id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
            },
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                {
                    var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
                    if (idTokenHint != null)
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

and this page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
new AuthenticationProperties
{
RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5000"
},
OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
}
```

it always say request not authenticated.

Client in IS is like this:

```
new Client()
{
ClientId = "mvcClient",
ClientName = "MVC Client",
//AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

               // RequireConsent = false,

                // where to redirect to after login
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                // where to redirect to after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                    StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                    StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                    StandardScopes.Roles.Name,
                    "NamfusAPI"
                }
```

and scope like this:

```
return new List()
{
StandardScopes.OpenId, // subject id
StandardScopes.Profile, // first name, last name
StandardScopes.OfflineAccess, // requesting refresh tokens for long lived API access
new Scope()
{
Name = "NamfusAPI",
Description = "Namfus API",
Type = ScopeType.Resource,
IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
Claims = new List()
{
new ScopeClaim(ClaimTypes.Name),
new ScopeClaim(ClaimTypes.Role)
}
}
};
```

Please suggest how to do this. Thanks

Comment: anyone can suggest how to create web form client with identity server 4?

Comment: Check the samples for IdentityServer3: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient

Comment: i see they have used response type like this  ResponseType = "id_token token", but when i use, i get invalid response type. When i try  ResponseType = "id_token code", I see that n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken is null. why it is null ?

Comment: Enable logging in IdSvr